# Unable to locate specified base class mx.core.WindowedApplication

Tags: apache-flex, air

While compiling mxml file ,I'm getting the following error..
**Unable to locate specified base class mx.core.WindowedApplication**

Its working for `<mx:Apllication>` But its not working for windowedApplication

Comment: Are you using Flash Builder?  Have you created an AIR project or a web project?  If you're using the command line tools; are the AIR specific Flex libraries in your class path?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com :: I am using command line tools,Yes i have all the things in my classpath.And now it works for me,Please find my solution below ..Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there’s nothing wrong with your Flex SDK / AIR installation it just your probably using:
mxmlc
when you should be using:
amxmlc

The first command ‘mxmlc’ is to compile the MXML to SWF, whereas the second ‘amxmlc’ is to compile the MXML to the AIR App platform.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I suspect this is probably a solution; however I think it represents an incomplete understanding of what goes on.  If you check the bin folder of your Flex SDK installation, there is a bat file named amxmlc.  All that does is launch mxmlc with a different profile. ( AKA +configname=air ).  That profile tells MXMLC to compile the app using the frameworks/air-config.xml file instead of the frameworks/flex-config.xml file.  I suspect the source of the problem is compiling the app that uses classes which do not exist in the library path.

Comment: Also, I've found that I needed to target the Flex 3.6A SDK, instead of the Flex 4.6 SDK to get support for WindowedApplication